# Как без ошибок вывести элементы двумерного массива на php?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть вот такая конструкция, которая выводит 15 элементов из массива (15 - это максимум в самом массиве):
    `for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) { echo ... }`

Но есть проблема - массив не всегда содержит 15 элементов. Бывает и 1 и 2 всего, тогда в браузер сыпятся ошибки.

Как сделать вывод всех элементов из массива без ошибок?

Пробовал так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($json); $i++){ echo ... }
```

Выводит всего два элемента.

Элементы тащатся отсюда:

```
$Result = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=15&type=video&q='.$search.'&key='.$youtube_key.;
$Result2 = file_get_contents($Result);
$json = json_decode($Result2);
```

Где тут сам массив - я не понял ... и видимо он многомерный?

Сделал вывод `var_dump($json)`:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (6) {
    ["kind"]=> string(26) "youtube#searchListResponse"
    ["etag"]=> string(57) ""I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/Wj2ZLGAfwqw4io35vUD2ESCm58U""
    ["nextPageToken"]=> string(6) "CA8QAA"
    ["regionCode"]=> string(2) "RU"
    ["pageInfo"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
        ["totalResults"]=> int(1000000)
        ["resultsPerPage"]=> int(15)
    }
    ["items"]=> array(15) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) {
            ["kind"]=> string(20) "youtube#searchResult"
            ["etag"]=> string(57) ""I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/Ae6ehuMAZpZWFRSMBSnvB6U4XZA""
            ["id"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
                ["kind"]=> string(13) "youtube#video"
                ["videoId"]=> string(11) "he8nz5tAZrw"
            }
            ["snippet"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (7) {
                ["publishedAt"]=> string(24) "2016-03-29T05:17:40.000Z"
                ["channelId"]=> string(24) "UCfaZw8XH_zmAVkBst_MPD6w" 
                ["title"]=> string(97) "Unboxing New Spiderman Battery-Powered Ride On Super Car 6V Test Drive Park Playtime Fun Ckn Toys"
                ["description"]=> string(160) "Hi guys today Spiderman will be unboxing and asemmbling this new super spiderman kids electric ride on 6 volt car.This would have to be our favourite car so ..."
                ["thumbnails"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
                     ["default"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
                         ["url"]=> string(46) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/he8nz5tAZrw/default.jpg"
                         ["width"]=> int(120)
                         ["height"]=> int(90)
                     }
                     ["medium"]=> object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
                         ["url"]=> string(48) "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/he8nz5tAZrw/mqdefault.jpg"
                         ["width"]=> int(320)
                         ["height"]=> int(180)
                     }
                     ["high"]=> object(stdClass)#9 (3) {...}
                     ["channelTitle"]=> string(8) "CKN Toys"
                     ["liveBroadcastContent"]=> string(4) "none"
                 }
             }
            [1]=> object(stdClass)#10 (4) {...}
```

элементы выводятся в таком виде:
`$element[$i]`.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе вывод `var_dump($json)`

Comment: сделал вывод для примера

Comment: Отлично!. А теперь скажите, какие именно элементы нужно выводить?

Comment: У `json_decode` есть классный параметр `$assoc`, который удобнее ставить в `true` - в этом случае stdClass будет представляться в виде обычного массива со строковыми ключами. Работать с таким будет гораздо удобнее, чем с stdClass. Подробности и примеры: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для обхода массивов функцию [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
    // получение данных
    foreach($json as $key => $value) { // проход по данным
        // обработка или вывод данных, например:
        var_dump($key);
        var_dump($value);
    }
    // дальнейшая работа
```

Comment: такой вариант не подходит. там сложный массив, и выводить нужно уже чистые данные.

Comment: @Ариан так вы можете использовать вложенные циклы. А про чистые данные вообще не понял

Answer (score 0):

В PHP нет многомерных массивов вроде `arr[x,y]`, индекс массива всегда один. Зато есть вложенные массивы, это когда элементами одного массива являются другие массивы. Индексация в этом случае будет `arr[x][y]`. Вложенность произвольная, каждый элемент массива может быть любого типа - и массивом тоже

@Ариан, используйте вызов `$json = json_decode($Result2, true);` вместо `$json = json_decode($Result2);`. Это позволит вам работать с обычными массивами, а не с экземплярами stdClass. Подробнее: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Далее, возвращается вам JSON. Ваш массив результатов находится в поле корневого массива с именем `'items'`, то есть чтобы перебрать все результаты, нужно пройтись по полю `$json['items']` циклом `foreach()`

```
if ($json && isset($json['items']) && is_array($json['items'])) {
    foreach ($json['items'] as $item) {
       // Здесь можно работать с одним результатом, например вывести его в читаемом виде и с превью
       var_dump($item);
    }
} else {
    // А здесь можно обработать ошибки, возможно результатов не будет, или что-то еще пойдет не так. Читайте документацию API внимательнее
}
```

Длинная проверка в `if` позволит вам убедиться, что JSON корректно распарсил ответ, в ответе есть поле `'items'`, и элемент в этом поле - массив результатов, а не какое-нибудь число

Если хотите, можете использовать и цикл `for`, только оформляйте его правильно:

```
if ($json && isset($json['items']) && is_array($json['items'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($json['items']); $i++) {
        $item = $json['items'][$i];
        // Работаем с одним элементом $item
    }
}
```

Довольно громоздко, не правда ли? `foreach()` делает все то же самое, при желании можно также получать индекс элемента массива:

```
foreach ($json['items'] as $i => $item) {
    // Работаем с элементом под индексом $i, а сам элемент - $item
}
```

Обратите внимание - индексом. Не номером. Индексом массива может быть и строка, и число. Обращаться к неизвестному массиву через `arr[0]` не совсем корректно, возможно, там нет элемента с индексом 0, зато есть `arr['first']`

Теперь что касается обработки каждого элемента. Каждый элемент - тоже массив, как видно из вашего примера, и тоже содержит вложенные массивы, например в `$item['snippet']['title']` хранится заголовок результата, а в поле `$item['snippet']['thumbnails']` - три элемента-массива c индексами `default`,`medium` и `high` соответственно. Например, чтобы показать превью для результатов, можно использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
if (isset($item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']) && ($medium_thumbnail = $item['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium'])) {
    print '<img src="'.$medium_thumbnail['url'].'" width="'.$medium_thumbnail['width'].'" height="'.$medium_thumbnail['height'].'" border="0" />';
}
```

Код не самый красивый, но общий смысл передает. Если честно, нужно еще проверить наличие полей `url`, `width`, `height`, но это я оставлю вам как упражнение

Не забывайте делать проверку элементов массива до того, как попытаетесь их использовать - дело cовсем не в Notice сообщениях PHP при обращении к неопределенному индексу массива, а в заведомо некорректных пустых данных там, где вы ожидаете что-то хорошее. *В языках вроде C/C++ подобные вызовы закончили бы жизнь вашей программы )),* но PHP довольно либерален в этом вопросе. Вызова [isset](http://php.net/Isset) в большинстве случаев вполне хватает для проверки наличия элемента по указанному ключу, вроде `if (isset($arr['key'])) ...`. Можно также проверять и сразу несколько вложенных ключей, то есть `if (isset($arr['key1']['key2']['key3'])) ...` вернет `true` только в том случае, если все три ключа в каждом вложенном массиве определены и не равны NULL